# Covariant derivative along a curve vs pullback connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $\nabla$ denote the Levi Civita connection on a Riemannian manifold $M$. Suppose that $c$ is a curve and $X$ a smooth vector field. My question is: how are the following covariant derivatives
$$
\bigl(\nabla_{\dot c(t)}X\bigr)(c(t)),
$$
and 
$$
\bigl(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}X\circ c\bigl)(t)
$$
related? In the second case we consider the pullback connection (or material derivative). I am confused.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the two expressions "live" in different spaces but are essentially the same. The first one is in $M$ and the second one in the interval $(a,b)$. You might be interested in a proposition that some texts call "Naturality of the Riemannian Connection".